# How do you change the MARK period in the new rsyslog configuration file?

Tags: rsyslog

The old $MarkMessagePeriod no longer works. In my attempt to set the MARK period in the new configuration file, I changed the following line

```
`#module(load="immark")`
```

to

```
`module(load="immark" MarkMessagePeriod="600")`
```

But I get the following error:

> rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 26: parameter 'MarkMessagePeriod' no known -- type in conf file? [v8.2002.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

Answer (score 1):

This is the new syntax:

`module(load="immark" interval="600")`